# Code First EF Deploy Attempt by Method failed

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a asp.net mvc 2 on .net 4 with code first entity framework data access.

When I deploy to one server it works beautifully, no prizes for guessing it doesnt work on the other...the message however I cannot understand

Attempt by method 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Internal.Configuration.CodeFirstCachedMetadataWorkspace.GetProviderInvariantName(System.Data.Common.DbConnection)' to access method 'System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderFactory(System.Data.Common.DbConnection)' failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated .net 4 from 4.0.2**** to 4.0.3***

that fixed it

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a Code Access Security error to me.  Are both servers configured to run under Full Trust?